# Can I have some devices at building 2, connect to the building 2 server (WS2012) as it's gateway, and use that server's VPN connection to building 1?

Tags: vpn, remote, pptp

The situation is as follows

Building 1 (B1) is my main site. I have 1 Windows Server 2012 unit at B1 and B2. B1 is a PPTP server.

At B2, I have many devices. Most of these devices are constantly on a VPN connection to B1 (including the B2 server).

Can I set some devices at B2, such as IP phones that do not have VPN abilities, use the B2 server as a sort of "Default Gateway", and then have the B2 server route these devices over its VPN connection to B1?

I am aware that there are better alternatives, however most of those require more advanced hardware that I could not afford. I already know for sure that the B2 router does not support VPN connections (but it lets them through).

Comment: You should be able to do this with RRAS on the server at B2.

Answer (score 0):

All of your buildings should have been connected via l2, probably with VLANs. VPN, PPTP and all sorts of rakes that you keep on planting thoroughly cannot be justified by whatever reasons, don't do that. Sooner or later this field of rakes will be your professional tomb. Or ever worse - a tomb of someone who will come after you.